# Microsoft: Private Team with read only sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am looking to have a Private Teams site where members can contribute to a document library.  I want the corresponding Sharepoint site to be viewable by all authenticated users.

Currently when I create a private team site the corresponding Sharepoint site cannot be accessed by non members.

If I create the Private Team then go to Sharepoint and change permissions to public the Team now becomes public also.

Again, I need a private team site for contributors and a public (any authenticated user) Sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'Everyone except external users' to the SharePoint Online site with View only permission. This can be done via Gear icon in the upper right -> Site Permissions -> Invite People -> Share Site Only.